# How to change a theme's footer image

Tags: images, themes, footer

I inherited the administration of a site and want to make a few changes. It has a great customized theme that I want to keep. The first thing I want to change is an outdated footer. I uploaded my new footer image to the media library, copied the url, and went to the style.css page and commented out the old url and added the new one.

```
.footerimage {
    /*  background-image: url("/wp-content/themes/region2coastal/images/fema_rampp_logo.png"); */
    background-image: url("/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Logo.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center top;
    width: 100%;
    height: 92px;
    background-size: auto;
}
```

I Updated but the old footer image is still showing. I am assuming that I need to somehow add the new footer image to /wp-content/themes/region2coastal/images folder but I can't seem to figure out how to do that. Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Comment: It sounds like you're cached. It could be your browser cache (use a Chrome Incognito window, or a totally different browser, to test) or it could be your host's caching or a caching plugin. You can definitely reference an upload in CSS and still have it work. However - what's not safe is editing the theme directly, as when you update the theme, your change will be overwritten. You should check to see if your theme has a Custom CSS area where you can paste in that CSS or something a little more specific, and that won't get overwritten when the theme is updated.

Comment: Argghhh! Yep, the image was changed, I just had to clear the cache. Rookie mistake.

Comment: Happens to veterans too - all the time. Glad it worked! :)